# Using State Variable in Subscription and useEffect() in React for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, observable

I am having a `subscription`, which I set up in the `useEffect()` Hook. Based on a variable from the `store`, I want to execute code (or not) which is also part of the body of the `subscription`.

```
const variableFromStore = useSelector(state => state.variableFromStore);
const dispatch = useDisptach();

useEffect(() => {
    const subscriptionEvent = SomeModule.AddSubscription(event => {
        console.log(variableFromStore);
        if(variableFromStore) {
            dispatch(foo());
        }
    });
})
```

Initially, `variableFromStore` is false. However, during interaction with the App (which includes unmounting the component, because the App is moved to background), it gets set to `true`. Then, some time later, `subscriptionEvent` gets fired.

But, when I `console.log(variableFromStore)`in there, it is *always* `false`, eventhough the `redux debugger` tells me it is `true`...
Is it not possible to pass a `state/store` variable into a subscription?

I assume this is because I am setting up the `subscription` in the `useEffect()` hook, which only gets executed once. But, if I set it up like this

```
useEffect(() => {
    const subscriptionEvent = SomeModule.AddSubscription(event => {
        console.log(variableFromStore);
        if(variableFromStore) {
            dispatch(foo());
        }
    });
},[variableFromStore])
```

Wouldn't that reinitialize the `subscription` every time `variableFromStore` changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your useEffect callback runs only once, and the `variableFromStore` is enclosed by callback [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), to fix that, redux provides another way of getting the state from the store by calling the store [getState](https://redux.js.org/api/store#getstate) method, which returns your whole state object, so you need to import your store first, from wherever it was created, and call `getState` method, this way the same last value will be returned as per using the selector, but that is not affected by closure:

```
import store from '...'

useEffect(() => {
    const subscriptionEvent = SomeModule.AddSubscription(event => {
        const { variableFromStore } = store.getState()
        console.log(variableFromStore);
        if(variableFromStore) {
            dispatch(foo());
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: No, that's unlikely, since you still got that error, that could be the same issue, try using dispatch method from store as well https://redux.js.org/api/store#dispatchaction, but i doubt it though, could you please show the ```foo``` action code?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the useEffect with empty or without a dependency array, it will only run on the first render.

If you add the variable you want to use or run the effect on the variable's value change add that variable to the useEffect's dependency array.

Try this code down below and also check out [this documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for more.

```js
const variableFromStore = useSelector(state => state.variableFromStore);

useEffect(() => {
  const subscriptionEvent = SomeModule.AddSubscription(event => {
      console.log(variableFromStore);
      if(variableFromStore) {
          dispatch(foo())
      }
  });
}, [variableFromStore])
```

Comment: this is correct :)

Comment: Hmm... But that would also mean that the whole subscription block gets re-executed... Which I do not want. Additionally, the `subscription` should listen all the time, no matter if I execute `useEffect()` again or not...

Comment: Then you might want to move the subscription block to the body of the component. In that way, you only subscribe in the initial render. Then you can use the useEffect however you want.